# Getting as Network Error while recording via JMeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, neoload

While recording the Application using Jmeter after entering the credentials and clicking on login button getting as **Network Error**.

Not able to login into the application but while browsing the application no issue observed. Only when recording via Jmeter this Network Error is getting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNimF.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's something specific for your application, we cannot state what is the root cause by looking into the screenshot.

Things to check:

1. Console and Network tabs of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools)
2. [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file

Potential reasons I can think of:

- You haven't imported JMeter's certificate into your browser/operating system. Refer to **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) JMeter User Manual entry for more details
- You're behind a corporate proxy. In this case you need to [make JMeter aware of this upstream proxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) so it would be able to access the Internet

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates and will be able to just record your test using your browser with possibility to export recorded requests in form of JMeter [.jmx test script](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) afterwards